# match the name of a worksheet tab with a specific cell value automatically in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

how can I match the name of a worksheet tab with a specific cell value
automatically. In other words, If I change the value of that cell, the name of worksheet tab would change automatically to that value.

please make the answer step by step.

thank you my friends.

Answer (score 1):

See comments in code. This code must be attached to the sheet in which entries to cell A1 will change the name of the sheet. To do that, right-click on the name tab of the sheet and select `View Code`. Copy the code and paste it into the code pane (the large pane in the upper right area of the code editor.

To change the cell for name change entries from "A1", just change the cell address in the line `If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then`. Be sure to include the dollar signs.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Worksheet change event occurs when a change is made
    'to a cell's value in this sheet

    'Target is the cell (or cells) in which values have been changed

    'Trigger worksheet name change only when a new name is 
    'entered in cell A1
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

        'Don't change name if a formula is entered into cell A1
        'since worksheet change event does not trigger when
        'a formula is recalculated (in other words, name will not
        'change when the value of the formula changes
        If Not Target.HasFormula Then

            'Don't change name if no value in cell A1
            If Not Target.Value = vbNullString Then

                 'Do custom error handling in order to
                 'gracefully catch entry of invalid sheet names
                 'and other (less likely) errors
                 On Error GoTo ErrHandler

                 'The event will trigger only for the sheet to
                 'which the code for the change event is attached,
                 'so okay to refer to ActiveSheet
                 ActiveSheet.Name = Target.Value

            End If

        End If

    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Warn user of error 
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & ":" & Error(Err)

    'Turn default error checking back on
    On Error GoTo 0

    'And end the sub
End Sub
```